# How to connect postgresSQL using play 2.8 java

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, jdbc, playframework

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL from play 2.8 project using java (not scala). But unable to do. I am using JDK 11, Play 2.8.x version.

[image]

SBT dependencies:

```scala
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.3.1",
        jdbc,
        "org.playframework.anorm" %% "anorm" % "2.7.0",
        javaJpa,
        "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.4.32.Final",
        "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-java-jpa" % "2.8.8",
        "net.jodah" % "failsafe" % "2.3.1",
        guice,
        "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-core" % "4.1.1",
        "com.palominolabs.http" % "url-builder" % "1.1.0",
        "net.jodah" % "failsafe" % "2.3.1",
        ),
```

Config file:

```
db.default {
    driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase"
    user="postgres"
    password="root@123"
}
```

MyController

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    
     private DataSource dataSource;

      @Inject
      public MyController(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
      }
      
  public Result index() {
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
     return "connected database"
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return internalServerError("Database error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `MyController`? I believe you're injecting `Datasource` instead of `Database`.

Comment: package controllers;
import java.sql.*;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import javax.inject.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class MyController extends Controller {
 
  private DataSource dataSource;

   @Inject
   public MyController(DataSource dataSource) {
     this.dataSource = dataSource;
   }
   
  public Result index() {
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
     return "connected database"
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return internalServerError("Database error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}

Comment: Check out documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Accessing-the-JDBC-datasource, you need to inject `Database`.